# Problem in setting breakpoint in vs2010 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm new in the asp.net . I'm having one web page in asp.net which is developed in vs2010 & for design i'm using devxpress control. I've designed one page & the code behind file is "cs" file . I've used page load event. & set a break point to the page load event. but it is not showing me in the debug mode. And code which i've written in the page load that code is also not executing. I don't know why it is happened for my web page. Also i've used master page for designing my web page.

How to resolve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose the problem without seeing the code for the Page_Load event.

Comment: Have you tried just doing an iisreset?

start / run / cmd / iisreset

Comment: just create a page and try to debug it.

Comment: what process do you attach to?

Comment: thanks to all of you for replying . This issue is solved. It happened because of the `AutoEventWireup` which is in the @page directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the page ASPX on the first line there is the @Page directive. 
Check if there is the attribute CodeBehind on that line like this :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="*yourfile*.aspx.cs" Inherits="*Namespace.yourfile*" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are beginning with ASP.NET try this one :

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Debuging-Breakpoints.aspx

This one too :

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Stepping-Data-Viewing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not working with Internet explorer to debug your application?
Perhaps you just have to "Use Internet Explorer as default browser".

This description is for Silverlight pages but can work for ASPX too:
*Click on the web page that has your control (such as default.aspx) and choose “Browse with…” from the context menu.*

[image: Default Browser]

I also found [- this -](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Enabling-Internet-Explorer-for-Debugging-ASP-NET-AJAX.id-305946.html) to use Debugger.